# How can I retrieve Tinder API authentication?

Tags: bash, facebook, curl

> ```
> $ curl -X POST 
>         -H "X-Auth-Token: FB_AUTH_TOKEN" \
>         -H "Content-type: application/json" \
>         -H "User-agent: Tinder/7.5.3 (iPhone; iOS 10.3.2; Scale/2.00)" \
> https://api.gotinder.com/auth
> ```
>
> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>   100    69  100    69    0     0    105      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   105{"code":400,"error":"Missing authToken#NO_FB_TOKEN","error_no":40001}

Does this mean I go thet incorrect Facebook auth token? I'm following the specifications in this REST API: https://github.com/fbessez/Tinder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation you referred, I can see you are not sending the post data in the request body `{'facebook_token': INSERT_HERE, 'facebook_id': INSERT_HERE}`
Besides, the docs says `X-Auth-Token` is not required for `/auth`

Comment: Like this ``curl -X POST \
            -H "Content-type: application/json" \
            -H "User-agent: Tinder/7.5.3 (iPhone; iOS 10.3.2; Scale/2.00)" \
            -X POST -d "facebook_token":"xyz","facebook_id":"xyz" \
    https://api.gotinder.com/auth``?

Comment: I was trying to find my facebook token to check that, but I'd say the -d could be like ``-d "{'facebook_token': INSERT_HERE, 'facebook_id': INSERT_HERE}"``

Comment: Or ``curl -X POST https://api.gotinder.com/auth --data '{"facebook_token": fb_token, "facebook_id": fb_user_id}'``

Comment: Did you get your facebook_id and facebook token? I guess you can get them here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken

Comment: Do you know where to get the access token that I need to input?

Comment: I put my access token in the debugger and I get this ``1100370394586743|mMXBhH3m-pYyR2EswBpSbTBEHAQ``. What is thsi?

Comment: ``1100370394586743|mMXBhH3m-pYyR2EswBpSbTBEHAQ`` seems to be an App token (from one of your facebook applications), but I think you are looking for the User Token and the facebook user id.
Here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken you have to click on the User token debug button, not in the App token. By clicking there you'll get your user id.

Comment: There is no user token debug button. Can you provide a screenshot or something?

Comment: Check this screenshot, http://imgur.com/oCvDoVo I tested using the app token and user token, and the json data should be like ``--data '{"facebook_token": "<app_or_user_id>", "facebook_id": "<facebook_app_id_or_facebook_user_id>"}'``

Comment: Is it like this? ``12345 : Martin Doe`` The left is user_id? and the right is facebook_user_id?

Comment: Lol the response body is ``<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
``. Does that mean they changed the API?

Comment: Do you get the same result or were you authenticated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151978/discussion-between-polak-and-santafebound).

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been changed as per: https://github.com/fbessez/Tinder/issues/69

Now the request is

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.gotinder.com/v2/auth/login/facebook' \
--header 'platform: ios' \
--header 'User-agent: Tinder/7.5.3 (iPhone; iOS 10.3.2; Scale/2.00)' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
        "token": "{{facebook_token}}",
        "facebook_id": "{{facebook_id}}"
  }'
```

The changes are:

1. the URL endpoint
2. Payload key: 'facebook_token' is now just 'token'